# Flutter GetX setState

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

```
bool download=false; setState(() {download=true;});download==true?Text("new"):("old");
```

How to write this code by using get X without stateful widget.

Thank you;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first define a controller class

```
class ControllerClass extends GetxController{
 RxBool download == false.obs;
}
```

in your stateless class you can state a set with two ways

inject a controller first like this

```
 ControllerClass controller = Get.put(ControllerClass());
```

First:

```
    Obx(()=>controller.download.value == true?Text("new"):("old"))
```

in some function

```
downloadCondition(){
   controller.download.value == // true or false;

}
```

Second:

```
    GetBuilder<ControllerClass>(builder: (controller){ return 
     controller.download.value == true? 
    Text("new"):("old"));}
```

in some function

```
downloadCondition(){
   controller.download.value == // true or false;
 controller.update();
}
```

Comment: if you are using getbuilder you don't have to use RxBool, you can use simple bool too

Comment: yes this correct but it take around 10 sec to update

Answer (score 3):

try this first create a controller:

```
 class ControllerName extends GetxController {
    final download = false.obs;
    
       yourFunc(){
        download(!download.value);
   }
    }
```

i usually used obx then

```
    // You can also put your controller above on stateful or inside depends on you
       // final controller = Get.put(ControllerName());
        class YourPageName extends StatelessWidget {

       YourPageName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

     final controller = Get.put(ControllerName());

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Obx(()=>
            Scaffold(
           body: SafeArea(
             child: Column(
                 children:[
                      Text(controller.download.isFalse ? "Old" : "New"),
                      SizedBox(
                      height: 60,
                     width: 120,
                     child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                   primary: Colors.red,
                child: Center(
                   child: Text("Click")
                       ),
                     onPressed: ()=>controller.yourFunc(),
                         ),
                        ),
                 ]
                ),
            ),
          ),
          );
       }
        
        }
```